# Select rows with the latest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this problem. 
I can't think a query for find some values which are repeating in my table, I want to select only those with the latest/highest Scan Date(marked with yellow)
Here my table, name:Test 
[image]

Comment: What do you have so far? How can you have multiple latest scan dates for the same person?

Comment: Sorry but this database wasn't created by me. i have multiple lastest scan dates from the same person,  so i should create this query to select those Scan_Date

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate due to the way the data is ordered. The key to this question is handling the `SCAN_DATE` in the `GROUP BY` function which isn't covered in the two duplicate questions that are suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `MAX` function and `GROUP BY`. This should select the latest `SCAN_DATE` from your table

```
SELECT
    LAST_NAME
    ,FIRST_NAME
    ,MAX(SCAN_DATE)
    ,WEIGHT
    ,HEIGHT
FROM Test
-- If using SQL
GROUP BY LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, CAST(SCAN_DATE AS Date), WEIGHT, HEIGHT
-- If using MySQL
-- GROUP BY LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, DATE(SCAN_DATE), WEIGHT, HEIGHT
```

Comment: sorry, but with this query, i get  the last row of my table, instead of the yellow-marked rows

Comment: Can you have a look at the update. Also correct your tags to whether you're using `sql` or `mysql` as they have different syntaxes

Comment: it worked , thank you so much!!!